# How to make gradient shape-outside CSS div Box

Tags: html, css, sass

how to create this type of CSS div box[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]:

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gradient Div</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    div.Outer
    {
      width: 200px;
      border: 2px solid #00df82;
      border-radius: 5px;

      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 15px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    div.Inner
    {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;

      left: 155px;
      top: 8px;
      width: 70px;
      height: 54px;

      border-radius: 25px 5px 5px 25px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(#00df82, #34ef52);
    }

    #para
    {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="Outer">
      <p>Full Filled</p>
      <div class="Inner">
        <p id="para">95</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've answered this to the best of my CSS knowledge. There may be better ways of solving this problem. Here is an explanation of the parts:

`position: absolute;` allows HTML elements to be placed anywhere on the HTML page. 
`z-index: 1;` specifies in what order HTML elements will be displayed along the z-axis. 
 For example, if an HTML element has a z-index of 0 and another HTML element has a z-index of 1, the HTML element with a z-index of 1 will be drawn on-top of the HTML element with a z-index of 0.